# Is it possible to intercept the touch on a GlanceController and choose to show a specific view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, user-experience

I'd like to **intercept** the touch on a glance and get the watch kit app to present (push) a specific view from my storyboard.

Something like this:

```
// In GlanceController.m 

-(void)thisIsTheDefaultMethodThatIsCalledWhenTheGlanceIsTouched{
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"myViewController" context:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is no way to intercept the touch on a Glance, you can pass information from the Glance to your app. Use the `updateUserActivity:userInfo:webpageURL:` method on `WKInterfaceController` to coordinate Handoff like this:

```
[self updateUserActivity:@"MyActivityName"
                userInfo:@{ @"MyKey" : @"MyValue" }
              webpageURL:nil];
```

Then, in your Watch app, implement `handleUserActivity:` to push your controller.

Comment: At the moment I am not using handoff in my app. I am using a singleton object that remembers a key information and shows it either in the glance or in the extension interface

Comment: You may not be using Handoff now, but this is the only way to accomplish what you're describing. Use a Handoff activity type that isn't recognized on any other device and it will work great.